# How can I specify the IP address for each target in Prometheus-blackbox-exporter config?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Blackbox exporter only check the place which DNS Point to.
But I want to check the SSL certificate in several IP addresses, that means I have to specify IP to exporter for taking url to that IP to check SSL expiration.

The Grafana Dashboard which I use
https://grafana.com/blog/2020/11/25/how-we-eliminated-service-outages-from-certificate-expired-by-setting-up-alerts-with-grafana-and-prometheus/

Edit Server /etc/hosts file is not a good idea for me. Because there is not only one IPs for one domain.
＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
example what I want:

```
  - job_name: 'blackbox'
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx,tcp_connect_tls,icmp]

    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - https://www.google.com:142.251.43.4
        - https://www.google.com:172.217.163.36
        - https://www.yahoo.com:180.222.102.202
        - https://www.yahoo.com:180.222.102.201
        - https://www.yahoo.com:87.248.100.215
```

Or is there any better idea for monitor each domain in different IP addresses simultaneously via Prometheus and Grafana? For now we only can use nagios to do this, because nagios command "check_ssl_cert" have `--resolve` Option to specify IP.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer. The new version of blackbox_exporter is support the parameter "servername" to specify the FQDN.

servername=www.google.com&target=https://142.251.42.228

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).